# Checking for Identity Column

Tags: php, sql-server, information-schema

I am trying to find out if the table I am trying to merge into has an `identity` column (from a php application). The query that is being built is:

```
USE dhs;

select COLUMN_NAME as name 
from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
where TABLE_SCHEMA = 'dbo' 
and COLUMNPROPERTY(object_id(TABLE_NAME), COLUMN_NAME, 'IsIdentity') = 1 
AND TABLE_NAME = 'orders'
```

If I run this in Management Studio, I get the return value of `id` (which is what I expect). However, when I run the same query from my application, nothing is returned. I have given my database user full permissions, so it can't be a permission problem. Below is the php I am running (that currently returns false even though it should return 'id'):

```
$array = empty($array) ? $_POST : $array; //if no array is passed, use post
        $info = self::information_schema($db, $schema, $table);
        $clean = array(); //the hex-exscaped key values pairs that are matched against the database column names (so only items whose key matches a column name are used)
        $primary = array();// ON section array
        $update = array(); //the array for elements to update, each position is set to target.$k = source.$k
        $insert = array(); //The insert string, which is essentially array_keys($clean) minus any identity field with source. prepended
        $fields = array(); //fields to insert to with no source. prepended and no identity fields included
        $query= "USE $db 
                                select COLUMN_NAME as name
                                from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
                                where TABLE_SCHEMA = '$schema'
                                and COLUMNPROPERTY(object_id(TABLE_NAME), COLUMN_NAME, 'IsIdentity') = 1
                                AND TABLE_NAME = '$table'"; //this gets the identity column of table it has one (to prevent trying to insert into an IDENTITY field)
                    $handle = sqlsrv_query(self::$conn, $query);
        $value = sqlsrv_fetch_array($handle, SQLSRV_FETCH_NUMBERIC);
        var_dump($value);
```

Does SQL Server not allow you to select from `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` from outside SSMS?

Comment: You have of course made sure your variables are correct?

Comment: Did you print out the query from PHP and ensure that it is executing the query you think it's executing? Also [stop using INFORMATION_SCHEMA](https://sqlblog.org/blogs/aaron_bertrand/archive/2011/11/03/the-case-against-information-schema-views.aspx).

Comment: Yes, my variables are correct. The statement that I put at the top is the exact statement that gets echoed out by $query. I can copy and paste that into SSMS and it works just fine.

Comment: The strange thing is, I can log in as the application user in SSMS and execute the query just fine.

Comment: Have you used SQL Profiler to trace and verify the SQL that's being executed on the server?

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have access to Profiler at the moment.